# Change dedicated moderation time to a higher number

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Can we please change the suggested minimum time potential moderators should dedicate to the site to a more realistic number?

The [page for our elections](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8) read

> Due to the size of Stack Overflow (averaging nearly 2,000 flags per day!), moderation can be a significant responsibility - if you can't dedicate at least 30 minutes each day to help shoulder the load, please defer to those who can.

With no other numbers given to put that time into perspective, it can easily make potential candidates believe it doesn't take much longer. But the truth is: 30 minutes a day won't cut it.

When I was still an active mod, everyone would put in much longer. And that was needed to keep the flag queue down to acceptable numbers. If all of us had only put in 30 minutes, we wouldn't have managed that.

30 minutes really is not much. For anything that involves looking at context this is not enough to make a difference. Copy Editing a low quality post to salvage it can easily take a minute or five. Verifying and handling a sock puppet (let alone handling a voting ring) can take significantly longer. Same for answering posts on Meta or handling chat incidents. And you need to follow the Blue Room and the Teacher's Lounge to stay current.

Moderation is *a significant responsibility* indeed. It is also significant *work*. It's not something you do on the side easily and potential moderators should be given a fair idea of the average time it will take.

Comment: Also, is 2000 flags per day still an up-to-date figure? I don't know if I remember it correctly, but I think I read about a higher amount some time ago...

Comment: I nominate "If you can't dedicate the full 24 hours each day"

Comment: We mere mortals don't really know what it was like on the other side.  Could you give us a ballpark as to a number you think is close to what you experienced?

Comment: @Makoto BoltClock's comment above is quite accurate. Jokes aside, I would expect an hour or two to be more reasonable.

Comment: @honk In the last 30 days, 66474 flags were handled on SO, or about 2216 flags per day. However, only 27799 flags were directly handled by moderators, or about 927 per day. Community review queues have gradually shifted more of the flag burden away from moderators, which has been a positive thing.

Comment: @BradLarson: Thanks for the statistics! If the flags are no longer the greatest burden for moderators, then the text quoted in the question might in general need a larger revamp than requested by Gordon...

Comment: @honk - Flags are still what we spend almost all of our time on. That wording is still accurate, in that this volume of flags is what comes in. The community handling more of these flags has prevented the number from completely overwhelming moderators, but flags are still what we spend our time working on. The sentiment is correct.